# Why were my answers to a CSS question marked for deletion?

Tags: support, deletion

My [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74764473/5896591), to an old question about centering an element, substantially improves the knowledge base, since it styles only 1 element instead of 2. I even found a way to do it in the technology available at the time of the question, so I posted a [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74764483/5896591).

Why were both of my answers marked for deletion? There are no comments posted on either answer.

Comment: Only the user that marked them for deletion can answer that.

Comment: @Rubén As I mentioned, there are no comments posted on either answer. Are you saying that answers can be anonymously marked for deletion?

Comment: @personal_cloud regular users cannot see who voted for deletion. We can only see how deleted a post after it has been deleted.

Comment: No. I'm not saying that answers can be anonymously marked for deletion. I said what I said "Only the user that marked them (the referred answers) for deletion can answer that (why they voted to delete them)".

Comment: I will make sure to vote to delete the question later. We don't really need more answers around centering element. The site is plenty of them.

Comment: Just a guess, but it's pretty spammy to post two answers to the same question with such closely related content. Maybe someone didn't like that. Also, it's a subject that's been beat to death (that question should probably have been closed as a duplicate from the beginning).

Comment: That's a question from 2011... It doesn't need new answers, especially as it's linked to a canonical now.

Comment: @Cerbrus most of the userbase seems to disagree with that. There are dozens of ways to center something using CSS (and I'm sure some people will sneak in javascript ways) and by golly they all need to be documented in double the amount of answers!

Answer (score 6):

I assume that your answers were deleted because you answered an obvious duplicate.

When you see an old question that you want to answer you *need* to check if it's a duplicate, especially when it's about a fairly common task. Only post a fresh answer if you can't find an adequate dupe target.

If you have something useful to add to the existing answers on the dupe target you can write a new answer to that target, but please make sure that you aren't just replicating existing answers. It's certainly possible for old questions to need new answers, especially with technology like CSS & JavaScript that have evolved substantially in the last decade.

Sometimes in a dupe search you may find a related question with an answer that has helpful info, although it doesn't quite qualify as a dupe target. If you post a comment linking to the helpful info the system will link the questions explicitly by displaying each question in the Linked sidebar of the other question.